# Concrete explanation for how an equivalence relation is related to equivalence class and the notation employed

Tags: relations

I'm fairly comfortable with the definition of what the three equivalence relations are.
What I'm not comfortable and finding it above my head is how equivalence relation is closely related to equivalence class and the associated notation use to communicate the ideas.

Allow me to be be more specific.

Let $$\sim _n$$ denote an equivalence relation. 
For each $$\text{a$\epsilon $Z}$$, *we let $$\text{[a}]_n$$ denote the equivalence class containing* a.
What does the text in italic implies in a concrete sense?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but and equivalence class of an element consists of all the elements related to it under the equivalence relation.

Comment: To define equivalence class, one has to define equivalence relation. I do not understand how equivalence relation is related to equivalence class.
To go in on a limb, for each element a in a set, there exists an equivalence class if there are 'some' elements in the set that satisfy some equivalence relation.

Comment: There are more than three equivalence relations: are you referring to the axioms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we have some equivalence relation $\sim_n$ on a set $Z$. Then if two elements $a,b \in Z$ are related through the relation $\sim_n$, we write $a \sim_n b$. From this, we can talk about the *equivalence class* of an element $a \in Z$ with respect to the relation $\sim_n$ and we denote this $[a]_n$. An equivalence class is simply all the elements that are related to $a$ through $\sim_n$, or more formally
$$[a]_n = \{b \in Z \mid a \sim_n b\}.$$
So the equivalence classes are constructed from the equivalence relation. Indeed, different equivalence relations on the same setwill give rise to different equivalence classes.

Answer (score 0):

In general if $(E,\mathcal{R})$ is a set with an equivalence relation the collection of sets $E_x=\{y\in E, x\mathcal{R}y\}$ form a partition of $E$.

More specifically $E_x\neq \phi$ and for $x\neq y$ $E_x=E_y$ if $x\mathcal{R} y$ or $E_x\cap E_y=\phi$ otherwise

Comment: I might be understanding it. Thanks

Comment: On a tangent, is it possible to extend the idea of equivalence relation and equivalence class to the concept of bijective, surjective and injective function?